# VSCode and IDLE not outputting blinking text appropriately

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-idle

I'm trying to make some text blink in a simple bit of Python code.  I am running Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.  The following code works properly (blinking) when I run it through Python in a regular terminal window:

```
from termcolor import colored, cprint

cprint('Hello world!' 'blue', attrs=['blink'])
```

However, when I try to run it through VSCode the output doesn't blink, and when I run it through IDLE, it's even worse... the output is as follows:

```
[5m[34mHello world![0m
```

Has anyone seen this before, or have any ideas what my problem could be?

Comment: These two IDEs simply do not implement a terminal emulation that supports these control codes.  There's nothing you can do about this, other than running your code in an actual terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Termcolor outputs ANSI terminal control codes.  Those code only have the intended effect when output to an ANSI terminal (such as VT100) or a program emulating such.  IDLE is a editor and shell for developing programs.  It prints as well as it can what your program outputs, without interpretation.  Each '[' open bracket in your example was preceded by the escape character, but that does not print.

I presume that the situation is similar with VSCode, except that it recognizes and deletes the code that follow the escape char.

I have considered added a terminal mode to IDLE to interpret such codes, but someone has to write a patch.